# Why won't this program print out anything?

Tags: python

```
def getPhoneNumber():
    """Returns phone number if valid"""
    validPhoneNumber = False
    emptyString = ''

    #prompt user for phone number
    while not validPhoneNumber:
        phoneNumber = input('\nEnter phone number with last four letters being alphabet'\
                            '(910-555-book):')

        #check if valid form
        if len(phoneNumber) != 12 or phoneNumber[3] != '-' or \
           phoneNumber[7] != '-':
            print('Invalid Entry - Must be of the form 910-555-book')
        else:
            validPhoneNumber = True
            while validPhoneNumber:
                if not phoneNumber[0:3].isdigit() or not phoneNumber[4:7].isdigit():
                    print('Non-digit entered before end')
                    validPhoneNumber = False
                if not phoneNumber[8:12].isalpha():
                    print('Non-alphabet entered in last four characters')
                    validPhoneNumber = False

    return phoneNumber

def displayPhoneNumber(phoneNumber):
    """Displays alphabet to phone number"""

    translate = {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':2, 'd':3, 'e':3, 'f':3, 'g':4, 'h':4, 'i':4,
                 'j':5, 'k':5, 'l':5, 'm':6, 'n':6, 'o':6, 'p':7, 'q':7, 'r':7,
                 's':7,'t':8,'u':8,'v':8,'w':9, 'x':9, 'y':9, 'z':9,'0':0,'1':1}

    print(phoneNumber[0:8] + translate[phoneNumber[8]] + translate[phoneNumber[9]]\
          + translate[phoneNumber[10]] + translate[phoneNumber[11]])


#Main 
print('This program will allow you to enter a phone number with the last four')
print('characters being in the alphabet and print out the corresponding numbers.')

terminate = False
while not terminate:

    phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber()
    displayPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)

    #continue?
    response = input('Enter another phone number? (y/n):')
    if response == 'n':
        terminate = True
```

Is there something wrong in `getPhoneNumber`? Because if there wasn't and it was passed to `displayPhoneNumber`, I would think that it would print. So my guess is it's in `getPhoneNumber`. This is my first time trying to use the `isdigit` and `isalpha` using slice notation, so maybe it's in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        while validPhoneNumber:
            if not phoneNumber[0:3].isdigit() or not phoneNumber[4:7].isdigit():
                print('Non-digit entered before end')
                validPhoneNumber = False
            if not phoneNumber[8:12].isalpha():
                print('Non-alphabet entered in last four characters')
                validPhoneNumber = False
```

If `phoneNumber` is a valid phone number, `validPhoneNumber` will never be false, and so the `while validPhoneNumber` loop will run forever.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.